# No response data after call a function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file called `login.php`, in this file there is the box to fill from send the login data to the server. Now when the user press the login button, this code is fired:

```
 var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + 'application/controllers/user.php/ajax_check_login';
 var postData =
 {
      'username': $('#username').val(),
      'password': $('#password').val()
 };

 $.post(postUrl, postData, function(response)
 {
      // Some stuff..
 }, 'json');
```

the `postUrl` is valorized correctly by:

> http://localhost/App_Name/application/controllers/user.php/ajax_check_login

now I have a list of my own controller that allow me to manage the web app. One of this controller is `user.php`, how you can see I call the `ajax_check_login` function. This function check if the data passed from this request exists in the database and if are correct. This is the content:

```
public function ajax_check_login()
{   
    echo "Test?";
    try
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password']))
        {
            throw new Exception('Bad credentials!');
        }

        $this->check_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if($user_data)
        {
            $output[] = array(
                "some content..."
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(AJAX_FAILURE);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception $exc)
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'Exception ' => array(exceptionToJavaScript($exc))
        ));
    }
}
```

Now, at the top of all I inserted an echo, just to test if is printed. But nothing. In the Chrome console I get:

> This request has no response data available.

I don't know what is wrong, someone could enlighten me?

Comment: Can you try to remove the `, 'json'` parameter from the `$.post` call, just to make sure the problem is not caused by Chrome trying to decode something, which is not valid JSON (which is not because of the `echo "Test?";`, and maybe some PHP error message, if there is any)? You should put the `, 'json'` back when you're done debugging.

Comment: If I remove the `json` and put this `console.log("response => " , response);` inside the `$.post` I can see the `response => ` printend in the Chrome console, but no response returned from the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'd like to check what's the return from server, say HTTP200 without contents? or Error 500. Why I'm saying this because your snippet tells there are few variables/functions missing. Check my comments:

```
public function ajax_check_login()
{   
    echo "Test?";
    try
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password']))
        {
            throw new Exception('Bad credentials!');
        }

        $this->check_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if($user_data) // $user_data is never defined in this function, and it's not a global variable
        {
            $output[] = array(
                "some content..." // syntax error; here missing end parenthesis
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(AJAX_FAILURE);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception $exc)
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'Exception ' => array(exceptionToJavaScript($exc)) // unknown function exceptionToJavaScript(); it could encounter fatal error
        ));
    }
}
```

Second, I will suggest you send header to define you're sending JSON encoded content, and exit() after echo. See example:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(/** return **/);
exit();
```

Comment: nope, just delete some line of code for show method in the example.. Anyway the problem isn't fixed, no response returned.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the function has never been executed? Can you log in PHP? Please try to log at the first line of the function to clarify, e.g. `error_log(__METHOD__)`;

Comment: Did you log either the function is executed? I suspect it didn't execute or execute as expected, so suggested you to log the `__METHOD__` in it. Of course, it's better using debugger. Hope it help...

Comment: Please share your code, I'll be glad if I can help.

Comment: I thought you're going to send me the affected files.